# parse json to object ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I looked into different resources and still get confused on how to parse a json format to a custom object, for example

```
class Resident
  attr_accessor :phone, :addr

  def initialize(phone, addr)
      @phone = phone
      @addr = addr
  end
end
```

and JSON file

```
{
  "Resident": [
    {
      "phone": "12345",
      "addr":  "xxxxx"
    }, {
      "phone": "12345",
      "addr": "xxxxx"
    }, {
      "phone": "12345",
      "addr": "xxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

what's the correct way to parse the json file into a array of 3 Resident object?

Comment: Parse this JSON into a ruby hash, then walk that hash and create Resident objects.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is that by using JSON.parse(jsonfile) ?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks I got that part but how to fit in new object? Is it using class_variable_defined or something else?

Comment: Just a note to say that you need to remove the trailing comma after the "xxxxx" , else JSON will complain.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following code is more simple:

```
require 'json'

data = JSON.parse(json_data)
residents = data['Resident'].map { |rd| Resident.new(rd['phone'], rd['addr']) }
```

Answer (score 109):

Today i was looking for something that converts json to an object, and this works like a charm:

```
person = JSON.parse(json_string, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

This way you could do `person.education.school` or `person[0].education.school` if the response is an array

I'm leaving it here because might be useful for someone

Comment: imho the best way to do it.

Comment: Convenient, but not a custom object.

Comment: Worked for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON` you can just call `from_json(json)` and your object will be mapped with those values.

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :name, :age, :awesome

  def attributes=(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      send("#{key}=", value)
    end
  end

  def attributes
    instance_values
  end
end

json = {name: 'bob', age: 22, awesome: true}.to_json
person = Person.new
person.from_json(json) # => #<Person:0x007fec5e7a0088 @age=22, @awesome=true, @name="bob">
person.name # => "bob"
person.age # => 22
person.awesome # => true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'json'

class Resident
    attr_accessor :phone, :addr

    def initialize(phone, addr)
        @phone = phone
        @addr = addr
    end
end

s = '{"Resident":[{"phone":"12345","addr":"xxxxx"},{"phone":"12345","addr":"xxxxx"},{"phone":"12345","addr":"xxxxx"}]}'

j = JSON.parse(s)

objects = j['Resident'].inject([]) { |o,d| o << Resident.new( d['phone'], d['addr'] ) }

p objects[0].phone
"12345"
```

Comment: That's not bad, but you could use the `Enumerable#map` instead of each.

Comment: I added my idea as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

We recently released a Ruby library `static_struct` that solves the issue. [Check it out](https://github.com/mezuka/static_struct).