# How to get data and how to write the server side code using json in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I created a ROR project by using scaffolding, just created one basic project. How would I go about passing the data using json which must be obtained from the URL?

**In the mentioned code below, I have to get the data(name of user) and send it via json - that's what I would like to do - how can i go about it?**

hotels_controller.rb

```
**class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /hotels
  # GET /hotels.json
  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotels }
    end
  end
  # GET /hotels/1
  # GET /hotels/1.json
  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotel }
    end
  end
  # GET /hotels/new
  # GET /hotels/new.json
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotel }
    end
  end
  # GET /hotels/1/edit
  def edit
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  end
  # POST /hotels
  # POST /hotels.json
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @hotel, status: :created, location: @hotel }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @hotel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PUT /hotels/1
  # PUT /hotels/1.json
  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.update_attributes(params[:hotel])
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @hotel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /hotels/1
  # DELETE /hotels/1.json
  def destroy
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to hotels_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end**
```

how to get the those data using json,how to write the server side code.

**In my source code using ror  scaffolding,now what i want how to parse the data using json**

Comment: this IS your server side code. not quite sure what do you mean?

Comment: we have to do any more code for sending data,i have to send these code using json to android apps@PuneetGoyal

Comment: Please refactor your question, because it's really confusing. What you really want to do?

Comment: how to write json code for this project?@PuneetGoyal

Answer (score 0):

I cant explain for every action, but here's one example

```
  def show
    user_json = @params[:user] #'{"name": "User1", "age": 35}'
    user = json.parse(user_json)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I want how to write json code for getting the data from user and how to parse the data @gprasant

Comment: Dude i have source code for ror used scaffolding,now what i want how to parse the data using json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723094/parse-json-to-object-ruby 
This is what youre looking for

Comment: ya dude you are correct,but i will ask onething to u,in my code thy will get the name from the user and display it,for that one how i can do

Comment: you given an one link,in that link you can see the json file,for that we need to create json file,that what i want

Comment: Dude ,i will tell you one thing,in that above mention code,what i given in question,we have to get the data of the name from the user and send the data via json,that what i want to do,how can i do