# Extracting specific JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I receive (similar to) the following JSON data:

```
    {"accountId"=>"some-private-really-long-account-id",
     "stats"=>
      {"score"=>
        {"globalScore"=>
          [{"key"=>"lifetimeScore", "value"=>"571",

          "key"=>"someOtherKeyHere", "value"=>"someValue"}]}
```

I am not quite sure how I would get the lifetime score. I've tried doing stuff like this:

```
puts data["globalScore"]["lifetimeScore"]["value"]
```

But that doesn't work. (`data` is of course the JSON data received).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parse json to object ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723094/parse-json-to-object-ruby)

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(body)` to convert your json to a hash. Then use `hash.dig('stats', 'score', 'globalScore', 0, 'value')` to run queries on that hash.

Comment: Looks like the json data you posted is missing some "}", can you post the original one?

Comment: The original JSON data is wayyyyy too long.

Comment: @Phlip that worked thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that `data["globalScore"]["lifetimeScore"]["value"]` doesn't reference a valid "path" within the JSON.  Better formatting helps to clarify this:

```
  hash = {
    "accountId" => "some-private-really-long-account-id",
    "stats" => {
      "score" => {
        "globalScore" => [
          {
            "key"   => "lifetimeScore", 
            "value" => "571", 
            "key"   => "someOtherKeyHere", 
            "value" => "someValue"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

This Ruby hash has some issues since a hash can't actually have multiple values for a given key, but that aside,

```
hash['stats']['score']['globalScore'][0]['value']
```

is a perfectly valid way to access the 'value' field.

My point is that the problem with the original question is not that hash#dig(...) should be used (as shown by @Phlip), it is that the "path" through the Hash data structure was actually invalid.

```
hash.dig("globalScore", "lifetimeScore", "value)
```

will fail just like the bracketed syntax in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse(body)` to convert your json to a hash. Then use `hash.dig('stats', 'score', 'globalScore', 0, 'value')` to run queries on that hash.